# MySQL Will Not Start

Tags: mysql

Can't get MySQL to stay up, it might be corrupted data. Cent/cPanel server.

root@net [/etc]# service mysql status
ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found

**Attempted Fix:**  I edited etc/my.cnf and specified the PID and confirmed it exists.

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
max_allowed_packet=268435456
max_connections = 300
max_user_connections = 35
wait_timeout=40
connect_timeout=10
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25165824
open_files_limit=10000
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

**Attempted Fix:** I tried creating a new pid and specifying it.

```
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
Create the directory /var/run/mysqld/ and give it proper permissions -
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

But still errors
    ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!           group,v         mailproviders/
    passwd,v                rpm/                     trustedmailhosts
    Starting MySQL..... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).

So at this point the logfile looks pretty gnarly.

MySQL Log
http://pastebin.com/d7uCMKPN

---

I have set the innodb_force_recovery=3  in my.cnf  and it still wont' come up.
Does anyone have any idea's on what else I should try to fix this?

Comment: I'd restore from backup, quite some tables missing.

Comment: can you please share the installation directory of MySQL?

Comment: root@net [/var/lib/mysql]# pwd
/var/lib/mysql

The server is running cPanel.

Answer (score 3):

Try to kill all MySQL process in safe mode using following command and start again.

```
root@net []# killall -9 mysql mysqld
root@net []# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Comment: Aye thank you. I've had to restart this many times while troubleshooting. 

I was able to keep it up long enough to repair lot of tables. At this point I'm just going to migrate the db's and files to a new installation.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the level of corruption involved with this error, I was not easily able to fix all errors in the log.

1. After editing etc/my.cnf and forcing recovery mode (Level 3 was enough) and restarting, I was able to repair many of the tables.
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
2. I upgraded/re-installed MySQL and I was also able to copy the databases out and will be installing them on a fresh installation as I believe the corruption is pandemic on the system at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You should check mysql is running if yes try it. Also you can check it from activity monitor for macOS

```
sudo chown -R mysql mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64 // change ownership
cd mysql-8.0.16-macos10.14-x86_64/support-files/
sudo killall mysqld
./mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing the following directory: `/var/lib/mysql/mysql`

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/mysql
```

This leaves your other DB related files in place, only removing the mysql related files.

After running these:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then reinstalling mysql:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

It worked perfectly.